# Flash IDE path to AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there any easy way to get a path (a sequence of points) from the flash IDE into actionscript code?

for example if you want to draw an outline for a gameworld that you want to use as collision object and now in AS3 you'd like to get the vertices of that path you drew.

what i did so far was to create a lot of dummy movieclips, place them on the vertices of the drawin path and call them "dummy01", "dummy02", "dummy03" and so on, and then in AS i iterated over the children and rebuilt the path that way, but that's really ugly and i'm sure there must be a better way to do it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(The following instructions apply for Flash Professional CS5)*

1. Select the shape you want to extract the vertices from.
2. Create a new .jsfl file *(File > New... > Flash Javascript File)*. Paste the code below:

   ```
   var vertices = fl.getDocumentDOM().selection[0].vertices;
   var resultArrayString = "var vertices:Array = [";
   for(var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
       resultArrayString += "{x:" + vertices[i].x + ", y:" + vertices[i].y + "}" + ((i < vertices.length - 1) ? ", " : "];");
   }
   fl.trace(resultArrayString);
   ```
3. Press the "Run script" button (gray "play" button)
4. Look in the console, you will now have a complete Array containing the coordinates for all vertices for the selected object, ready for copy-pasting into your as3 code where you need it.

Example of output:

```
var vertices:Array = [{x:371.95, y:146}, {x:377.95, y:179}, {x:397.95, y:224}, {x:344.95, y:201}, {x:341.95, y:251}, {x:272.95, y:177}];
```

*Hint: if you need to use this script on a regular basis, save the .jsfl file and run it as a Command from within Flash.*